# ¿Como colocar ruta global para llamada de archivos o pantallas?

Tags: php, rutas

Tengo un proyecto el cual tiene en raíz un `index.php`, en su estructura `html` contiene un `navbar`y un `header`, los cuales se utilizan en muchas mas interfaces.

- `header`: Contiene una imagen de banner
- `navbar`: contiene menú que envía a otras pantallas definidas en otras rutas y archivos

El `navbar` y `header` se extrajeron en la ruta: `navbar/navbar.php` y `navbar/header.php` dentro del mismo proyecto, para llamar ambos archivos en conjunto se usa: `navbar/index.php`

contenido en `navbar/index.php`

```
<?php echo ROOT_PATH ?>
<?php include ROOT_PATH.'navBar/header.php'; ?>
<?php include ROOT_PATH.'navBar/navbar.php'; ?>
```

contenido de básico de `navbar/header.php`

```html
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <?php echo ROOT_PATH.'Img08/banner-portal-guerrero.jpg'?>
        <a href=""><img src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH.'Img08/banner.png'?>" class="card-img-bottom" /></a>
    </div>
```

contenido de básico de `navbar/navbar.php`

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="https:/"><img class="card" src="./Img08/icon.ico" /></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarTenencia">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="modulo/ModuloExterno">cobro </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="Impuestos" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        example
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarImpuestos">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="./PRC/login/index.php?opc=1"> textExample </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="./PRC/login/index.php?opc=18">text example</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

para evitar problemas con las rutas a las que hace referencia el menú, imágenes y demás recursos se creo el archivo `dirs.php` el cual contiene lo siguiente.

```
<?php 
    define('ROOT_PATH', __DIR__.'/');
?>
```

El a modo de prueba solo se estableció

- `src="<?php echo ROOT_PATH.'Img08/banner.png'?>"` en `navbar/header.php` para ver que `ROOT_PATH` cumple su función y obtiene la imagen.
- `<a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH.'modulo/ModuloExterno'?>">cobro </a>` para ver si redireccióna a la pantalla correcta.

**ninguna de las acciones anteriores funciona**

la estructura base del proyecto puede definirse de la siguiente manera.

```
proyecto
  modulo
  |  moduloExterno
  |  |  index.php
  Img08
  |  banner.jpg
  navbar
  |  header.php
  |  index.php
  |  navbar.php
  index.php
  dirs.php
```

---

### Información sobre ejecución del proyecto

para realizar la ejecución del proyecto utilizo **wampserver64 3.2** el cual instala lo siguiente

- php 7.4
- apache 2.4
- mysql 8.0

para probar todo el código realizado en php, se debe realizar lo siguiente

1. ejecutar **wampserver** para que levante los servicios.
2. colocar el proyecto en la ruta de **wampserver** que en mi caso es: `C:/wamp64/www`
3. Después de pasar mi proyecto a **wampserver** la ruta queda `C:/wamp64/www/proyecto`

para ejecutar el proyecto tiene que estar levantados los servicios de `wampserver`, en el **navegador** colocar `localhost/proyecto/`, esto ejecuta mi archivo index.php o index.html

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120164/discussion-on-question-by-richard-como-colocar-ruta-global-para-llamada-de-arch).

Answer (score 0):

En mi primer comentario yo hablaba de *definir constantes en cascada* para mantener en un solo archivo (`dirs.php`) **todas las rutas** del proyecto. No me refería solamente a definir una constante para el directorio raíz, sino para todos tus directorios y que luego en todas partes uses esas constantes.

Viendo todo el hilo de comentarios y el lío que se ha armado, parece que no entendiste ese aspecto fundamental para resolver el problema.

Significa que si este es tu árbol de directorios:

```
proyecto
  modulo
  |  moduloExterno
  |  |  index.php
  Img08
  |  banner.jpg
  navbar
  |  header.php
  |  index.php
  |  navbar.php
  index.php
  dirs.php
```

Vamos a definit *constantes en cascada* para **todas tus carpetas**.

Asumimos que `proyecto` se encuentra en tu directorio raíz. Entonces en el archivos `dirs.php` definimos esto:

```
define('ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('PROYECTO', ROOT_PATH.'proyecto/');
define('MODULO', PROYECTO.'modulo/');
define('MODULOEXT', MODULO.'moduloExterno/');
define('IMG08', PROYECTO.'Img08/');
define('NAVBAR', PROYECTO.'navbar/');
```

Cuando hablo de *definir en cascada* me refiero a que para los sub-directorios que están dentro de otros directorios se usa primero la constante que existe para ese directorio.

Luego, y **es preciso que entiendas bien esto**, donde quiera que necesites incluir un archivo o referir una ruta de cualquiera de tus archivos, **sólo tienes que usar la constante de ESE directorio seguido del nombre del archivo que quieres referenciar/mostrar**.

Por ejemplo:

En `navbar/index.php`:

```
#Incluimos el archivo donde se definieron las constantes
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'dirs.php');

#Incluimos los archivos usando directamente la constante
#del DIRECTORIO EN QUE SE ENCUENTRAN

include NAVBAR.'header.php';
include NAVBAR.'navbar.php';
```

Veamos otro ejemplo, en `navbar/header.php`

```
#Incluimos el archivo donde se definieron las constantes
include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'dirs.php');

<div class="container-fluid">
    <?php echo IMG08.'banner-portal-guerrero.jpg'?>
    <a href=""><img src="<?php echo IMG08.'banner.png'?>" class="card-img-bottom" /></a>
</div>
```

Como ves, en cada caso se usa la constante propia del directorio específico. Parece que entendiste que en todo había que usar `ROOT_PATH` ¿? ...

En este último ejemplo, supongo que la imagen `banner-portal-guerrero.jpg` se encuentra en el directorio `Img08`.

Si has entendido bien el concepto, no deberías tener problema con ninguna ruta.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120177/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-como-colocar-ruta-global-para-llamada-de-arch).